# i am trying to update my data using Repository but i connot see the existing data in my EditProduct view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz7y8.png)

ProductController for saving edited data

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SaveProduct(int id)
{
    bool products = _productRepository.UpdateProduct(id);
    if (products)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the edit operation fails
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

I cannot edit my data.

while this is my EditView

```
@model ProductModel


<h1>Edit Product</h1>
<form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="SaveEditProduct">

    <label asp-for="Id" readonly></label>
   

    <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
    <input asp-for="ProductId" /> 

    <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
    <input asp-for="ProductName" />

    <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
    <input asp-for="ProductQuantity" />

    <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
    <input asp-for="ProductPrice" />

    <button type="submit"Submit</button>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i connot see the existing data in my EditProduct view

Have a look at [Part 6, controller methods and views in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-8.0), you need to return the model to the view.

For example:
The HttpGet Edit method takes the movie ID parameter, looks up the movie using the Entity Framework FindAsync method, and returns the selected movie to the Edit view. If a movie cannot be found, NotFound (HTTP 404) is returned.

```
// GET: Movies/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var movie = await _context.Movie.FindAsync(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```